# fabric: how to double tunnel

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

Situation:
A and B are remote hosts.
Local machine can SSH into A, but not B.
B ONLY accepts SSH connections from A.

Question:
Is it possible to use fabric on the local machine to execute commands on Host B, preferably without having to install fabric on A?

Answer (score 13):

I managed to achieve this with [env.gateway](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/env.html#gateway) as follows:

```
from fabric.api import *

env.forward_agent = True
env.gateway = 'user@remote_MachineA'
env.hosts = ['user@remote_MachineB']

def function1():
  run('hostname')
```

`env.forward_agent = True` is there only to enable forwarding of your local SSH agent to the remote end

Alternatively, you can use ssh ProxyCommand, [example here](http://backdrift.org/transparent-proxy-with-ssh) and tell fabric to use your `~/.ssh/config` using `use_ssh_config = True`, documentation [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/env.html#use-ssh-config)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this might to the trick:

https://gist.github.com/856179

Comment: Tried this and it does exactly what the OP was asking for +1

Answer (score 3):

Since Fabric v1.5+ there is a method called `remote_tunnel` to solve cranberry situation

I have used a simple command (hostname) to illustrate the solution but any other command may be used instead. As you can see, we have invoked a command to be executed on remote_machineB from local_machine by using remote_machineA as jump host:

```
from fabric.api import settings, env, run, remote_tunnel

env.hosts=["user@remote_machineA"]

def funct1():
    def func1b(host):
        with settings(host_string=host):
            run("hostname")

    with remote_tunnel(remote_port=22022, local_port=22,
                       local_host="remote_machineB", remote_bind_address="0.0.0.0"):
        funct1b("user@remote_machineA:22022")
```

If you execute this fab file in local_machine this is what we get:

```
[user@local_machine ~]# fab hostname_check
[user@remote_machineA] Executing task 'hostname_check'
[user@remote_machineA:22022] run: hostname
[user@remote_machineA:22022] rtunnel: opened reverse tunnel: (u'X.X.3.75', 55804) -> ('X.X.3.78', 22) -> ('remote_machineB', 22)
[user@remote_machineA:22022] out: remote_machineB
[user@remote_machineA:22022] out:

Terminated
```

To do so it is very important to configure this jump machine ssh daemon with `GatewayPorts yes`. Otherwise remote tunnel would be accessible only from localhost.

Check:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:22022         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

versus:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22022           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

For more info check official documentation http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.remote_tunnel

Answer (score 2):

I'll just leave this here: http://www.popcornfarmer.com/2009/01/ssh-tunneling-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

As a variation on yeforriak's answer, if you only want to do this for an individual task, you can do:

```
from fabric.api import *

@with_settings(forward_agent=True, gateway='user@remote_MachineA')
@hosts(['user@remote_MachineB'])
def function1():
  run('hostname')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to answer the SSH part: Yes, you can set up a double tunnel -- one SSH from local to A that tunnels from a secondary local port (like 2121) to port 21 on B, and then you can SSH to localhost:2121 and login on B. I've done stuff like that with PuTTY.

Implementing that in fabric is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

In **Fabric 2+**, the API has been reorganized and the module `fabric.api` no longer exists, thus deprecating several answers on this page.

Addressing the question of "double tunnel" is still possible in this modern API, and still uses the concept of **gateway**, but relies on the `Connection` objects.

```py
from fabric import Connection

c1 = Connection('remote_machineA', user='user')
c2 = Connection('remote_machineB', user='user', gateway=c1)
c2.run('hostname')
```

Note that this answer is only valid if we interpret the statement *B ONLY accepts SSH connections from A* as *Due to network restrictions, [...]*.

Both hosts A and B should have your **local SSH public key** as authorized key (so, in some sense, B *does* accept SSH connections from the local machine). The public keys stored on A are not used to log on B.

Comment: This answer has been elaborated using Fabric 3.2.2.