# How can I tunnel SSH through 2 gateways to a remote host using Fabric?

Tags: python, ssh, fabric, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to figure out how to use Fabric to simplify SSHing into and running commands on a machine separated by two gateways. The setup looks like this:

```
Local host -> Gateway 1 -> Gateway 2 -> Remote host
```

I've taken a look at responses to [fabric: how to double tunnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161548/fabric-how-to-double-tunnel), as well as http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/usage/env.html#gateway but these don't seem to accomplish what I'm after.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Can you put a script on gw1 to run a fabric script connecting to remote host through gw2 ?

something like:

1. in your local fabric ssh to gw1 and run cmd1.sh in gw1
2. in gw1 the cmd1.sh will run a fabric command to connect to remote host using gw2. this means you need fabric in gw1.

hope it helps.